# spring cron for running every hour at 35th minute

Tags: java, spring, cron, spring-scheduled

I have a job that is scheduled to run every hour and I am using spring cron (0 0/35 * * * ). I am expecting the job to run at the 35th minute every hour but I noticed that the job gets triggered at the 35th minute and also at top of the hour. I am not sure why, any suggestions?

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Spring CronSequenceGenerator docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html), the `/35` in `0 0/35 * * *` effectively means "every minute that's a multiple of 35", which includes 0 - if you only want it to trigger at 35 minutes after each hour, just use `0 35 * * * *` (which includes all 6 parameters it wants).

Comment: worked like a charm! but I have not tested @daBigBug suggestions, which also seem to be correct. But Spring cron is a defintely different. Thank you all for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Your cron expression is incorrect, so change it to `0 */35 * * *` which runs only for every 35 minutes

Answer (score 0):

I think your fields are out of order. The Spring Cron documenation seems to say that Spring uses standard cron expressions. https://crontab.guru is a good tool for checking cron expressions.

https://crontab.guru/#0_0/35_*_*_* shows

> “At minute 0 past every 35th hour from 0 through 23.”

Whereas https://crontab.guru/#35_*_*_*_* shows

> “At minute 35.”

I think you need to use `35 * * * *`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Cron starts minutes at beginning of each hour (as we mention * for hour field). An alternative way of achieving your goal (**executing a task at every 35th minute**)can be as follows -

> Make your cron trigger for every 5 minutes and increment a counter
>   everytime the cron is triggered. Once the counter reaches 7 (i.e. 35
>   mins in your case), execute your goal and set the counter back to 0.

And if you want your goal to be **executed at 35th minute of each hour**, you should try

```
35 * * * *
```

Hope this helps!